# AR on Android - movement within an area

Tags: android

I am totally new to Android development. I'm not looking for code but what I am looking for is suggestions for how I could approach a problem. Essentially I am looking for suggestions for how I could have a predefined square (consisting of 4 gps points) representing a square. When the app user physically moves (with their phone) outside of the grid area, a message is displayed onscreen telling them that they're outside the area.

I envisage having to use gps coordinates to determine if a user moves outside the area. However I'm looking for advice on how to tackle the problem of the user moving around with the phone in their hand. I imagine that the GPS would have to constantly poll the GPS service to determine the coordinates of the user as they move (on demand) in order to determine if the user is outside the area. However, I'm sure that this is inefficient due to battery exhaustion and also having to constantly poll the GPS service to get the current coordinates of the user as they are walking. Is there perhaps some sort of app for the android that can dynamically determine a user's coordinates within a predefined area locally without having to constantly poll GPS for coordinates? I'm shooting in the dark here. Any suggestions appreciated!

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

You'll find that there are many ways, with varying degrees of accuracy, to get someones location.  LocationManager is a service on android devices that takes care of dispatching location updates.

What your application would do is register a listener to the gps that says, in broad temrs, 'tell me when the users position changes by more then 10 meters, no more then once every 5 seconds'.  This gives a broad set of operational guidelines to the LocationManager about how to service your request.  It sounds like your use case would require GPS, because of the specifics of what you're request needs to be able to tell you.

Take a look at the documentation for LocationListener and LocationManager, thats where you would start.

Comment: Ok. That provides a good starting point. If I may, I have just one further question for now. Would it be possible to determine if a user reaches a boundary area in relatively 'real-time' using the locationlistener? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you should be able to using  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double, double, float, long, android.app.PendingIntent)   However, you should test this live as I've found that many of the described behaviors behave a bit different then you'd expect.